# bootstrap component tabs, carousels etc not respond

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angularjs-routing, bootstrap-tabs

Until my contact page was a static HTML ie contact.html the bootstrap component tab, carousel etc work fine

as soon as I used ngRoute, routing to a partial view these components functionality no longer worked. is anyone ever had this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... I believe you/we need to wire up Bootstrap components using JavaScript. $('#myModal').modal(options) type stuff.

Comment: do you mean using jqurey on top of the default bootstrap.js?

Comment: Maybe... I think it's not supposed to mix angular and jquery as a best practice but I'm still baby steps here so it might be better to wait for someone that actually knows about the business here :)

Comment: i heard we could use the [angular bootstrap-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)

Comment: Here is a link I found some time ago. That might help. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

Comment: yep i looked at that before that is why i said it needs angular bootstrap ui

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I found out that Twitter bootstrap style works out of the box with AngularJS.

However, to use components that rely on javascript, you need to go to other frameworks.

Bootstrap part of [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has some "migrated" components you can use. I tried a few and they work straight out of the box. (copied and pasted examples given with the components)

[Quantum UI](http://quantumui.org/) also has some nice working components. I tried a few and I'm personally thinking of using those instead.